# Can't authenticate personal Microsoft account against Azure DevOps using MSAL

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to setup authentication against Azure DevOps using MSAL. I've followed [Microsoft's sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/ManagedClientConsoleAppSample) but I can't get it to work with personal Microsoft accounts. Whenever I try to login with a personal account I get the following error:

> This username may be incorrect. Make sure you typed it correctly. Otherwise, contact your admin.

In the sample I have only changed `ida:Tenant` to `"common"` and `ida:ClientId` to my application id. I've setup my App Registration by following the guide in the sample except for the "Supported account types" which I've set to:

> All users with a work or school, or personal Microsoft account can use your application or API. This includes Office 365 subscribers.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 1):

When configuring the application to use your app registration, you need also find the key `ado:OrganizationUrl` and replace the existing value to the URL of your Azure DevOps organization. Please note: This must use HTTPS. As it mentioned in [Configure the application to use your app registration](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/ManagedClientConsoleAppSample#step-3-configure-the-application-to-use-your-app-registration).

If you already replaced the `ado:OrganizationUrl`, you may have a try to change the Supported account types back to "Accounts in this organizational directory only" to see if it works for troubleshooting.

Comment: No effect. And I don't think that the ado:OrganizationUrl isn't the problem since it isn't used at all until the ListProjects method is called. I'm stuck during the login that is performed on line 77: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/blob/master/ManagedClientConsoleAppSample/Program.cs#L77

Answer (score 0):

I spent a little bit time to get the samples working and the key steps required to accomplish this are:

1. the Microsoft personal account need to be added to an Azure active directory tenant. As MSAL uses Azure AD as a fundamental infrastructure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/228067/invite-or-add-personal-ms-account-to-azure-ad.html

2. Link the Azure Ad tenant (with the Microsoft personal account) to the Azure DevOps service Instance.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops

To complete the sample, I used my MS personal account to sign up a free Azure account (so that I can test the Azure AD stuff), and used the same account to request a free Azure devops service account.

Thanks

Comment: in App.Config(e.g. ManagedClientConsoleAppSample) those 3 settings need to be changed: <add key="ida:Tenant" value="" />
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="" />
                   
        <!--URL of Azure DevOps organization-->      
 <add key="ado:OrganizationUrl" value="" />

Answer (score 0):

In your question you mention:
"I'm trying to setup authentication against Azure DevOps using MSAL. "

So, the goal is to let Microsoft Account users logon to some part of Azure DevOps using MSAL? I'm curious what the exact use case is, but let's assume I understand you correctly.

The first thing that comes in mind is, are those users already invited to the AzDo organization? Please read [here how to do this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-external-user?view=azure-devops)

Doing this will add them to the Active Directory as a guest like this:

[image: External user in AAD]

Alternatively if you just want to invite these users to Azure, please use the invite from: [https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_UsersAndTenants/UserManagementMenuBlade/~/AllUsers](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_UsersAndTenants/UserManagementMenuBlade/%7E/AllUsers)

[image: Invite external users]

Answer (score 0):

[This site](https://support.fyidocs.com/hc/en-us/articles/4407763706777--This-username-may-be-incorrect-Make-sure-you-typed-it-correctly-Or-contact-your-admin-when-signing-in-to-Microsoft) suggests this error occurs when the user doesn't have multi-factor authentication setup. You may need to have your Microsoft account setup with MFA.

Comment: I already have that